# Why does vector::push_back and emplace_back call value_type::constructor twice?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo&){cout << "constructed by lvalue reference." <<endl; }
    Foo(Foo&& ) {cout << "constructed by rvalue reference." << endl; }
};
```

then I insert into a vector:

```
Foo foo{};
vf.push_back(foo);
```

The output is surprising:

```
constructed by lvalue reference.
constructed by lvalue reference.
```

I assume it got copied when passing parameters, so I tried:

```
vf.push_back(move(foo));
```

and

```
vf.push_back(forward<Foo>(foo));
```

The output are slightly different due to move semantics but still calling constructor twice:

```
constructed by rvalue reference.
constructed by lvalue reference.
```

Why the constructors got called twice? How much performance does it impact? How can I avoid this?

---

I am using **mingw-gcc-4.7.1** on Windows Vista

Total example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo&){cout << "constructed by lvalue reference." <<endl; }
    Foo(Foo&& ) {cout << "constructed by rvalue reference." << endl; }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp)
{
    vector<Foo> vf;
    cout << "Insert a temporary." << endl;
    vf.emplace_back(Foo{});

    Foo foo{};
    cout << "Insert a variable." << endl;
    vf.emplace_back(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Exact output:

```
Insert a temporary.
constructed by rvalue reference.
Insert a variable.
constructed by lvalue reference.
constructed by lvalue reference.
```

Comment: @delnan `Foo foo{}` does not output anything.

Comment: what compiler/library are you using. I don't see your behavior on gcc4.9

Comment: @jrok I found this when the vector was not empty...

Comment: @a.lasram I am using mingw-gcc 4.7.1

Comment: On gcc 4.7.2 under Linux, I see only one.

Comment: Can you show an SSCCE, please?

Comment: @jrok It is the actual example I am using. I was just playing around with vector.. I did `vf.push_back(Foo{})` and it only output once, and I added another 2 lines of code as shown above and got 2..

Comment: Reallocation...?

Comment: I meant a small example that we can copy paste and run as is. Right now there's probably relevent parts that are missing.

Comment: I used VS 2012 and VS 2013 preview and only get one output. How do you define vector vf?

Comment: @texasbruce: try giving your vector an initial size (>=2)

Comment: Note that `std::vector<Foo>` will copy instead of move when reallocating, since Foo's move constructor is not declared `noexcept`.

Comment: @Mat like `vector<Foo> vf(3);` ? I got even more weird output: `Insert a temporary.
constructed by rvalue reference.
constructed by lvalue reference.
constructed by lvalue reference.
constructed by lvalue reference.
Insert a variable.
constructed by lvalue reference.`

Comment: That's not even more wierd, considering what you did.  What Mat should have said is give your vector an initial capacity >=2, via `vf.reserve(2);`

Comment: [It's reallocation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4420909b5b2003c4b375f480f7eaf834-c944ac6b0eed3bfc48b1f78a894f6965).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh it's normal now... i put `vf.reserve(3)` immediately after declaration, and each insert only output one constructor message now! So it is reallocation issue?

Comment: @Cassey Thanks for the example! It is indeed confusing! How can I avoid these? Do I have to always use reserve? Then what is the advantage of using vector over array...

Comment: @texasbruce Use reserve, or be sure to put the `noexcept` qualifier on your move constructor. Or just don't worry about it - `std::vector` is specified to have amortized constant time for appending to the end (i.e., the size has to grow exponentially so reallocations become less common as the vector gets larger).

Comment: @texasbruce: The advantage is that vector can have a dynamic size, and can be resized at runtime, via `reserve`.  You don't _have_ to `reserve`, it's just faster if you do.

Comment: No, you don't always have to use reserve (but if you know for sure how much space you will need, then it certainly does'nt hurt).  What you have to do is stop worrying about these copies.  They're really not a big deal.

Comment: @texasbruce: Also, as many people have mentioned making your move constructor move-only will make a big difference as well.  Do that.

Comment: When you insert items into a vector does it to automatically create a copy because the vector stores everything on the heap.

Comment: @andre: It depends how you insert. For example, if you use `emplace`, then the object is constructed on the heap in the first place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you insert new items in a vector the vector may have to allocate more memory to fit those objects. When that happens it needs to copy all it's elements to the new memory location. That will invoke the copy constructor. So when you insert your element you're getting the constructor for that new element and the constructor when copying the previous element.

Comment: calling `vf.reserve(10)` may test this.

Comment: Most implementations of `std::vector` use `memcpy` when it has to move data to new locations.  The issue here is that the function being called has the parameter passed by value, and it calls another function that also has a passed by value parameter.

Comment: How can I avoid these? Do I have to always use reserve? Then what is the advantage of using vector over array...

Comment: @texasbruce you can't append or remove things from an array, it has a fixed size.

Comment: @ZacHowland: The only use `memcpy` for trivially-copiable types, of which `Foo` here is _not_.

Comment: When the storage is reallocated the objects should actually be moved, if possible, rather than copied. The object is being copied because the move constructor is not marked `noexcept`.

Comment: @bames53 I added noexcept to move constructor... and its the same output

Comment: @texasbruce For me it changes the one of the lvalue constructions to rvalue: http://ideone.com/OyY5jf

Comment: @texasbruce "How can I avoid these? Do I have to always use reserve? Then what is the advantage of using vector over array." Reallocations are done infrequently in order to meet the 'amortized constant time' complexity guarantee for push/emplace_back, so you may not need to avoid them. `vector` handling this complexity for you is one of many reasons to prefer it to raw arrays.

Answer (score 7):

```
  vector<Foo> vf;
  cout << "Insert a temporary." << endl;
  vf.emplace_back(Foo{});
```

What happens above is that a temporary `Foo` is created.

This temporary is then used to construct a `Foo` within the `vector`.  So a "constructed by rvalue reference" is what you asked for.

If you wish to simply construct the `Foo` in place, try:

```
  vs.emplace_back();
```

Next:

```
  Foo foo{};
  cout << "Insert a variable." << endl;
  vf.emplace_back(foo);
```

here you construct a non-temporary `foo`.  You then instruct the `std::vector` to construct a new element at the end of the list.

The interesting thing is that you get *two* construct by lvalue reference.  The second seems to be caused by the resize.  Why the resize causes you to be construced by lvalue reference, instead of rvalue reference, is a trick: if your `move` constructor is not marked `noexcept`, `std::vector` falls back on copy instead of `move`!

[Here](http://ideone.com/EZGK0j) is a live example illustrating the above principles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo {

public:
  Foo() {}
  virtual ~Foo() {}
  Foo(const Foo&){cout << "constructed by lvalue reference." <<endl; }
  Foo(Foo&){cout << "constructed by non-const lvalue reference." <<endl; }
  Foo(Foo&& ) noexcept {cout << "constructed by rvalue reference." << endl; }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp)
{
  vector<Foo> vf;
  cout << "Insert a temporary.  One move:" << endl;
  vf.emplace_back(Foo{});
  cout << "Insert a temporary(2).  Two moves:" << endl;
  vf.emplace_back(Foo{});
  cout << "Resize with temporary(3).  Two moves:" << endl;
  vf.resize(10);

  vector<Foo> vf2;
  Foo foo{};
  cout << "Insert a variable.  One copy:" << endl;
  vf2.emplace_back(foo);
  cout << "Insert a variable(2).  One move, one copy:" << endl;
  vf2.emplace_back(foo);
  cout << "Resize with variable(3).  Two moves:" << endl;
  vf2.resize(10);

  vector<Foo> vf3;
  cout << "Insert a nothing.  No copy or move:" << endl;
  vf3.emplace_back();
  cout << "Insert a nothing(2).  One move:" << endl;
  vf3.emplace_back();
  cout << "Resize with nothing(3).  Two moves:" << endl;
  vf3.resize(10);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

A common implementation of `std::vector::push_back` looks like this:

```
void push_back(value_type _Val)
{   // insert element at end
    insert_n(size(), 1, _Val);
}
```

As you can see, the input parameter is passed-by-value (so it is copied) in both the `push_back` declaration and the `insert_n` declaration.  Hence, the copy-constructor is called twice.

After cleaning up your syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo&) {cout << "constructed by lvalue reference." <<endl; }
    Foo(Foo&&) {cout << "constructed by rvalue reference." << endl; }
};


int main()
{
    vector<Foo> vf;
    cout << "Size = " << vf.size() << endl;
    cout << "Capacity = " << vf.capacity() << endl;

    cout << "Insert a temporary" << endl;
    vf.push_back(Foo()); // this is still very discouraged syntax

    Foo foo;
    cout << "Insert a variable." << endl;
    vf.push_back(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

You get the following output:

```
Size = 0
Capacity = 0
Insert a temporary
constructed by rvalue reference.
Insert a variable.
constructed by rvalue reference.
constructed by lvalue reference.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In this example, I'm using a standard version of std::vector (which passes by const-reference or by reference-to-reference).  The initial push_back call creates a capacity of 1 (and a size of 1).  The 2nd call creates a new block of memory, moves the first item, and copies the second (the newly added) item.

In terms of performance, you aren't going to take a big hit for small reallocations.  There are a few different common memory models used (the one with Visual Studio grows your capacity exponentially each time it has to grow to decrease the need for it in the future).  If you know you will be starting with 100 elements, you should reserve space when you create your vector so allocation only happens once, which will also prevent the need to move existing elements when inserting new elements (due to the fact that you won't be exceeding your capacity multiple times).

Comment: `push_back` takes the parameter by `const T&` (or `T&&`).

Comment: If you notice, I said "a common implementation".  I can't remember what one comes with mingw, but depending on your settings in Visual Studio (for example - which is where that exact code was copied from) you can end up with it by value.

Comment: The thing is, the standard has two overloads of `std::vector::push_back`, namely `void push_back(const T& x);` and 
`void push_back(T&& x);`. So this "common implementation" would seem to be non-standard.