# vector::emplace_back result to call destructor twice

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

Simple program is written as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class Test {
public:
    Test( int d ) : data(d), addr(&data) {

    }
    // Test( Test &src ) : data(src.data), addr(src.addr) { }
    const int data;
    const int *addr;
    ~Test() {
        delete addr;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << " Data is : " << data << '\n';
    }
};

int main( int, char**, char** ) {

    std::vector<Test> data1;
    data1.emplace_back( 98 );

    for( auto a : data1 )
        a.print();
    std::cout << "main";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output was
[image: program output]

**Possibly the reason was the destructor called twice**
*I tried to get some info from : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051600/destructor-called-twice-when-removing-element-from-vector) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260686/why-does-vectorpush-back-and-emplace-back-call-value-typeconstructor-twice)* but cant get clear vison.

Comment: `delete addr;` twice? Must be a typo. Anyway, you should only call `delete` on a pointer that was `new`ed.

Comment: `addr` is not a pointer that was returned from `new`. Passing it to `delete` has undefined behaviour. Why do you think you need to `delete` anything? (`delete` is not for getting rid of pointers, it's for getting rid of what they point to, and *only* if that thing was created on the free store with `new`.)

Comment: oh! that was where i went wrong. Yes I was assuming that when deafult constructor is called it dynamically assign the address. Anyway It is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the problem is the ***delete*** statement in destructor which is unwanted for non-dynamic data member.